# monero-wallet-cli Wallet asks for password on Ubuntu but not Windows

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

When running ./monero-wallet-cli it asks for a password on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but not when running on Windows Pro 10 where a password is not asked for.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Because the MSYS console is buggy and reports that the console is not a TTY. leading Monero to think it must read from a file (and thus not prompt). Apparently it works on a non MSYS console.

See https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/3951 for details.

Comment: Not sure this is a bug or not. Mining starts but that a password is not asked for.